# Close SSL connection correctly with OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, memory, memory-leaks, openssl, connection

I have SSL connection in main thread and have memory leak.

I close connection in this way (`_ssl — SSL*` object):

```
SSL_shutdown(_ssl);
SSL_free (_ssl);
```

But memory isn't freed correctly — after every new client some memory (~20kb) doesn't freed. I made an experiment: make many connections(~7000) and close them after establishing. Graph shows that memory was really growing up during all time. It's very important for me that memory will be unchangeable from connection to connection. Any suggestions?

Graph:
[image]

UPD:
All functions that I use:

It's executed once when server is start (I think it can't reason for increasing memory from connection to connection):

```
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
    SSL_METHOD* meth = TLSv1_server_method();

    _ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(_ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(_ctx, 1);

    if (!_ctx) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(_ctx, "keys/c1.crt", NULL) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(3);
    }


    SSL_CTX_set_verify(_ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(_ctx,1);

    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(_ctx, CERTF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(3);
    }
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(_ctx, KEYF, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(4);
    }

    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(_ctx)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the certificate public key\n");
        exit(5);
    }
```

It's executed for every connection in the start:

```
    ERR_remove_state(0);

    _ssl = SSL_new (ctx);
    if (_ssl == NULL)
    {
        _isValid = false;
        return;
    }
    SSL_set_fd (_ssl, _sd->get_num());
    int err = SSL_accept (_ssl);
    if (err == -1)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        _isValid = false;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me like memory use stabilised at 18.MB, but where did you get the data? Processes don't normally release memory back to the operating system, so if you're using an OS tool you won't see memory usage decreases.

Comment: In the absence of code (other than shown above), you should probably see Rescorla's [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part I)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part1.pdf) and [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part II)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part2.pdf). If the first call to `SSL_shutdown` returns 0, then you have to call `shutdown` to trigger a TCP FIN and then call `SSL_shutdown` a second time.

Comment: @jww: You don't need to call TCP shutdown before or in between calling SSL_shutdown. SSL shutdown is independent of TCP shutdown and you could even just SSL shutdown a socket and continue to use it plain after that. This is what the CCC command with FTP does, i.e. downgrade the socket back to plain. The first call of SSL_shutdown will just send the close alert (unless already sent) while the second wait for close alert from the peer (unless already received).

Comment: @jww No. You most definitely should **not** call TCP shutdown on an SSL socket. It interferes with the SSL `close_notify` mechanism and will cause that to prodiuce an error as though a truncation attack had been mounted.

Comment: @EJP - See Rescorla's tutorial on page 11 and the accompanying code on page 12.

Comment: @jww It doesn't say anything about TCP shutdown there. In any case my reference is [RFC 2216](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246) #7.2.1, which trumps any tutorial known to man.

Comment: @EJP - again, whatever... It really gets old arguing with you. If you want to reject Rescorla's tutorial, then so be it. He was one of the OpenSSL contributors, and he's one of the TLS WG chairs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to release all resources which you used in this connection. OpenSSL has a reference counter on these resources and some functions returns you something with an increased counter and some not, so you have to really look at the (often insufficient) documentation. OpenSSL which not keep track which resources you've allocated within this connection and give them automatically back once you've called `SSL_free`, you have to take care of this yourself.

There is not enough information of what you are really doing in your code to see where if there really is a leak and where it comes from. But as an example: if you called `SSL_get_peer_certificate` to get the certificate you have to explicitly free the memory because (from the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_peer_certificate.html)):

> The reference count of the X509 object is incremented by one, so that it will not be destroyed when the session containing the peer certificate is freed. The X509 object must be explicitly freed using X509_free().

Contrary to that the similar function [SSL_get_peer_chain](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_peer_cert_chain.html) will not increase the reference counter so you should not attempt to free the resources yourself:

> The reference count of the STACK_OF(X509) object is not incremented. If the corresponding session is freed, the pointer must not be used any longer.

So you have to actually look at each function you use and check if you need to free allocated resources explicitly or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have added some code to question, can you look at it?

Comment: The only leak I can see there is if `SSL_accept` fails, because then you forgot to `SSL_free` before returning. Apart from that their might be leaks in the (not shown) code you do between the `SSL_accept` and the `SSL_shutdown`.

Comment: there are no code between the `SSL_accept` and the `SSL_shutdown`, I try just freezing memory now. And `SSL_accept` doesn't fails. I found same problem on another site, but the issue was if ssl starts in another thread (not main).

Comment: I don't see where a leak should be and I don't even know if there is a leak at all. Your graph does not show show that it uses more and more memory. It looks more like that there is a limit.

Comment: @Vladislav : Were you able to figure out a solution for your problem? I am facing the same problem with my code where for every connection, memory keeps increasing during the day!

Comment: @cnu I decided that it isn't real problem, because it has the limit, probably Xcode doesn't free all memory as fast as it allocated.